# kendo grid mvc calculated column not formating

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

MVC 5, Kendo 2017.2.504

I can't get a calculated column to format properly (to currency).

I've tried using a javascript function call in the `ClientTemplate` but the js function is never called.

```
   .ClientTemplate("#=formatCurrency(TotalAmount*Deductibility)#")

   function formatCurrency(value) {
    var result = kendo.toString(value, "c");
    return result;
  }
```

Also tried using `kendo.toString` directly:

```
  .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(TotalAmount*Deductibility, 'C') #")

  .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(TotalAmount*Deductibility, 'c') #")
```

Here's the grid definition (only showing column needed). One thing to note,
the grid has expandable rows (defined in the `DetailTemplate`), the expandable rows use an ajax datasource but the outer grid does not. I think that is part of the issue, I'm using a `ClientTemplate` (in the outer grid) but the data source is not Ajax. Everything else about the grid is working as expected:

```
  Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
              .Name("TaxClass")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                 ...
                columns.Template(c => c.TotalAmount * c.Deductibility).Title("Amount Deductible").ClientTemplate("#=formatCurrency(TotalAmount*Deductibility)#")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "currency"}).Width(110);
                    })
             .DetailTemplate(
                 ...

             )
             .Filterable()
             .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server())
             .Render();

         }
```

Comment: I have prepared a sample dojo for you Is this what you are after? http://dojo.telerik.com/IbUKI if this is what you want I will expand out a full answer for you.

Comment: @DavidShorthose nice example, appreciate the dojo - very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred way is to do the calc in the viewmodel, but you could do something like this:

```
columns.Template(c => { })
       .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(deductibleAmount(data),'c')#")
       .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "currency"}).Title("Amount Deductible").Width(110);
```

Then add the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Passed data contains current row model
    function deductibleAmount(data) {
        return data.TotalAmount * data.Deductibility;
    }
</script>
```